# When we toggle between enable and disable safari extensions, where will the state go and sit on different mac os?

Tags: macos, mac, safari, safari-extensions

After some research got to know that security find-generic-password -l "Safari Extensions List" -g command gives the extensions and their states. The output of the command is not in readable format. I tried saving the password as a plist and opening it, but then it is same. Can someone please guide me how to get the safari extension enable/disable state on different mac versions?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i looked at this and it's a total hack.

Run command with the extension installed, you will see it's name within the field.

Delete the extension from ~/Library/Extensions/Extension_you_Want

Open Safari

Close Safari

Run command again

the item is missing from the password list